# Is it possible to create an android test "apk" running outside the target apk?

Tags: android

Is it possible to create an android test "apk" outside the target apk? Now what I know is need to test code(apk) within target apk.

Comment: with the test codes in  normal form, no. but if you export some test points in target apk, of cause we can run tests in test apk.

Comment: I tried to compile test code in a standalone apk, but it can not access target apk or can not find the target activity.

Comment: that what i said. you need make a new test framework.

Comment: What do you mean to make a new test framework? Can you please provide a demo to describe it? Thank you for your great help!

Answer (score 0):

Already solved. Remember to run the test with cmd. Here is the code snippet:

```
Runtime runtime = new Runtime();
String testPackage = "com.android.contacts.test";
String testRunner = "com.android.contacts.test.G11NInstrumentationTestRunner";
String command = "am instrument --user 0 -w " + testPackage + "/" + testRunner;
runtime.exec(command);
```

The testRunner is my customized InstrumentationTestRunner, you can simply use android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.